# Image (.png) not shown in Chrome

Tags: html, css, image

I made an image in paint.net and saved as .png. The image borders are visible, but there is no imagecontent. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="home.php"><img id="logo" href="../img/templog.png" /></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
  align: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Inside the brackets, there is a preview of the image and in the web (chrome) there are only borders..

thanks

Comment: What do you mean inside the brackets - is that in your IDE (Visual Studio, Webstorm etc)? That doesn't necessarily mean it is the correct path when it is on the actual website.

Comment: brackets its a software.. http://brackets.io/
it shows a preview of the images and colors and stuff when you hover it in the code.. the problem was href, change for src. i didnt understood why but its solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the second href with src,  `<img id="logo" src="../img/templog.png" />`

any types of image should appear in chrome

Comment: i am sure not.. it makes a preview in breckets

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer ok, try to use the same code in another browser and check if it works or not?

Comment: i tried in microsoft edge and its not showing up .. i dont have more browsers

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer try change the second href with src,or remove the dots .. from the path and let start with /

Comment: you are amasing .. you can edit your answer, its the scr, i would like to know why it happened now this, but for now its working !!! thanks

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer ^_^ good, I'm happy to read that , good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different image in chrome to see if that loads?

Comment: its not loading.. i tried an image that already loaded in other project in same conditions.. what can it be ?